# Make ABC Ordered List Items Have Bold Style

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have an html Ordered list with type set to "A"

```
<ol type="A">...</ol>
```

Thus, each list item will start with A, B, C, etc.

I would like to style the A, B, C letters to be bold. I have tried setting font-weight:bold; via css, but it didn't work. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

a bit of a cheat, but it works:

HTML:

```
<ol type="A" style="font-weight: bold;">
  <li><span>Text</span></li>
  <li><span>More text</span></li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
li span { font-weight: normal; }
```

Comment: You can also use a `<div>` instead of a `<span>` if you want.

Comment: @nueverest div is block level, dont nest those imo

Comment: Why do I need the css to address `li span` with `font` `normal`?

Answer (score 49):

As an alternative and superior solution, you could use a custom counter in a before element. It involves no extra HTML markup. A CSS reset should be used alongside it, or at least styling removed from the `ol` element (`list-style-type: none, reset margin`), otherwise the element will have two counters.

```
<ol>
    <li>First line</li>
    <li>Second line</li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
ol {
    counter-reset: my-badass-counter;
}
ol li:before {
    content: counter(my-badass-counter, upper-alpha);
    counter-increment: my-badass-counter;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/xpAMU/1/

Comment: How did I not know about CSS counters before this? That's sick (the good kind).

Comment: This works beautifully. My only criticism is that you mean "list-style-type" not "list-type" :) Oh and that this doesn't work in IE7 and below, but hey, not much does.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo on my part. Thanks, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Not great if the content goes onto a second line in the list item, i.e. I assume most people would want the beginning of the second line to be aligned with the beginning of the first line

Comment: @MarkR21 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428720/how-to-keep-indent-for-second-line-in-ordered-lists-via-css

Comment: Great stuff. Never knew about CSS counters before

Comment: +1, This answer should be promoted in post 2013 era... similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369843/is-there-any-way-to-make-numbers-in-ordered-list-bold

Comment: This solution does not work if the text gets longer (i.e. the lines need to wrap), see the updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xpAMU/500/ Here's a better way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369843/is-there-any-way-to-make-numbers-in-ordered-list-bold/35438316#35438316

Answer (score 10):

Are you sure you correctly applied the styles, or that there isn't another stylesheet interfering with your lists? I tried this:

```
<ol type="A">
<li><span class="label">Text</span></li>
<li><span class="label">Text</span></li>
<li><span class="label">Text</span></li>
</ol>
```

Then in the stylesheet:

```
ol {font-weight: bold;}
ol li span.label {font-weight:normal;}
```

And it bolded the `A`, `B`, `C` etc and not the text.

(Tested it in Opera 9.6, FF 3, Safari 3.2 and IE 7)

Comment: 99% of browser fixes always involves adding extra mark up. Maybe one day this wont be the case

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is a little old, but it still comes up first in a lot of Google searches. I wanted to add in a solution that doesn't involve editing the style sheet (in my case, I didn't have access):

```html
<ol type="A">
  <li style="font-weight: bold;">
    <p><span style="font-weight: normal;">Text</span></p>
  </li>
  <li style="font-weight: bold;">
    <p><span style="font-weight: normal;">More text</span></p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 7):

You could do something like this also:

```
ol {
  font-weight: bold;
}

ol > li > * {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

So you have no "style" attributes in your HTML

Comment: Having tried several of the other approaches on this page and others, to simply make an OLs number bold I so far like this method the most; at least so far. Cleanest, least convoluted. Only thing I did was add a class to OL so I could turn the bolded OLs on or off as it were...

Answer (score 4):

Another even shorter solution is to make use of `li::marker` now [widely supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker).
Like so:

```
ol li::marker {
        font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this also:

`<ol type="A" style="font-weight: bold;">`

```
<li style="padding-bottom: 8px;">****</li>
```

It is simple code for the beginners.

This code is been tested in "Mozilla, chrome and edge..