# CSS for displaying an indented ordered list with checkboxes before each list item

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'm attempting to set up an ordered list with checkboxes in front of each list item, something like this:

1. I would like this to have a checkbox to the left of the item number and wrap to the first word in the sentence, not to the item number.
2. Same deal as item number 1, want a checkbox to the left of the item number and wrap to first word in sentence.

I've figured out the indenting stuff using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10428720/27457), but haven't been able to get the checkboxes to show up on the same line as the `<li>`.  Is there any way to do this?

Here's a [jsFiddle I've been messing with](http://jsfiddle.net/syltech/9v97V/).

Comment: Start here: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Radio buttons cannot appear between <ol> and <li>

Comment: @Diodeus - thanks for the link.  They are not radio buttons: `<input type="checkbox" />`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/9v97V/2/

You can do something like this.  You put the input inside the list item, then absolute position it so it appears before the list item.

Most relevant CSS:

```
li input
{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -40px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made a new jsFiddle based on yours: http://jsfiddle.net/3VESY/1/

Basicly I've put the text in a span (could also be a div) and a float on the input. The span has a padding-left to create the indent.
Hope that's what you needed?

```
ol {
    list-style-type:decimal;
    margin-left:20px;
}

ol li span {
    display:block;
    padding-left:30px;
}
input
{
    float:left;
}
```

edit updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3VESY/1/ to add numbers

Comment: Thanks, but I need the list item numbers/letters as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            form{
                border: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
                text-align: left;
                }
    
            ol{
                margin-left:40%; 
                font-weight:bold;   
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <div class="container">
            <form action="/action.php">
                <ol type="A" style="color: red" >
                    <li><p >CSE</p></li>
                    <ol type="i" style="margin-left:-13%; color: blue">
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="op1">
                            <label for="cb1"> Artificial Intelligence</label>
                        </li><br>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" name="op2">
                            <label for="cb2">Machine Learning</label>
                        </li>   
                    </ol><br>
                    <li><p>ECE</p></li>
                    <ol type="A" style="margin-left:-13%; color: blue">
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="cb3" name="op3">
                            <label for="cb3">Embedded Systems</label>
                        </li><br>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="cb4" name="op4">
                            <label for="cb4">IOT</label>
                        </li><br>
                    </ol>
                </ol>       
            </form>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I thought it's understood now considering the above answers, if not just simply copy-paste my code in a .html file & run it. You'll get the look & feel in basic illustration, & then make style changes as per your need.