# Hanging indent on unbulleted list with CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to create a `<ul>` with no bullets (i.e. `list-style-type: none`) where the items have a hanging indent (all lines except first are indented). I do not mean that all `<li>` after the first should be indented-- rather that, if an `<li>` spans more than one line, all lines after the first should be indented within that `<li>`. How can I achieve this?

So far I've tried:

- `text-indent: 5px hanging`: no effect, `hanging` is not yet supported
- `text-indent: -5px; padding-left: 5px`: found this trick [here](http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/hanging-indents.shtml), but it did not work in this context
- the solution at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17556496/cross-browser-compatible-hanging-indent-for-lists), which didn't work for unbulleted lists

**NOTE**: I know that I can achieve this by other means (e.g. using `<p>`s instead of a list), but I am wondering whether it is possible with `<ul>`.

Comment: Can you post an example of what you're trying to achieve? It might help people answer your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add some padding and a negative `text-indent`.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 40px; /* Most browsers already have this by default */
}
li {
  text-indent: -20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hello<br />world<br />foo bar</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 20px
}
li {
  text-indent:-15px;

}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>test
    <br/>me</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks dippas. That is not what I'm aiming for though. I want a hanging indent *within* a single `<li>`. So if that item spans more than one line, all lines after the first should be indented.

Comment: Ok your question at first wasn't clear enough, I updated my answer