# ordered and unordered list issue on wordpress site (ul not working)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, list

i have searched this forum and didn't find any solution to this.
my WordPress blog list does not indent properly if the list element's content enters the second line. i found a fix on stackoverflow, [How to keep indent for second line in ordered lists via CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428720/how-to-keep-indent-for-second-line-in-ordered-lists-via-css), which i implemented as shown below:

```
.entry ol,.entry li {
margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
.entry ol {
counter-reset: foo;
display: table;
}
.entry li {
list-style: none;
counter-increment: foo;
display: table-row;
}
.entry li::before {
content: counter(foo) ".";
display: table-cell;
text-align: right;
padding-right: .5em;
padding-left: .5em;
}
.entry ul li {
list-style: inside disc;
list-style-image: none;
line-height: 19px;
}
```

after the above implementation, i got the proper indentation for my list, however, whenever i try to use an unordered it tends to appear as an ordered list. even worse, when i try to use and unordered list as a sublisting within an ordered list, (things get crazy), it appears as a continuation of my ordered list instead of appearing as an unordered.
see an example in the blog i am currently working on:

http://www.medhealthng.com/abdominal-pain/

EDITED
i edited my code to look like this:

```
.entry ol, .entry li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.entry ol {
counter-reset: foo;
display: table;
margin-left: 1.3em;
margin-right: 1.3em;
line-height: 19px;
}
.entry li {
    list-style: none;
    counter-increment: foo;
    display: table-row;
}
.entry li::before {
    content: counter(foo)".";
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: .3em;
    padding-left: .3em;
}
```

but the sublisting still cant work with unordered list

Answer (score 1):

your `::before` tag inside the `li` tag has a `counter(foo) "."` content.

simply use another content for it:

```
.entry > li::before {
  content: counter(foo) ".";
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: .5em;
  padding-left: .5em;
}
```

**EDIT**
if you want your sublist be an unordered List give the `ul` tag inside the `li` a class (i.e. `unordered`) and add following css:

```
.unordered > li::before {
  content: ".";
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: .5em;
  padding-left: .5em;
}
```

Comment: using another content will affect the numbering on my ordered list.. it practically takes away the numbers in my ordered list

Comment: well i thought you wanted an unordered list :P so if i get you right you want the subitems to be unordered, but the main list to be numbered?

Comment: yes, exactly... subs should be unordered and while main should be ordered.

Comment: edited, you should only use the counter(foo) for direct childs then!

Comment: thanks alot for your effort, that would be the obvious fix.. but I'm doing this for a friend who doesnt know a thing about css and since her blog is built on wordpress, she will always use the visual editor and not the html text area. isnt there another way to implement this fix ordered that manually adding the class to every unordered list?