# How to gain hanging indent list with CSS Counters?

Tags: css, html-lists, css-content

I'm trying to build a 3 level ordered list with CSS counters.

```
ol {
counter-reset: paragraph;
list-style-type: none;
margin-bottom: 1em;
font-weight: bold;
}

ol > li::before {
counter-increment: paragraph;
content: "§" counter(paragraph) " ";
}
...
```

Is there a way to accurately indent the 1st and 2nd level?

I know there is a way using something like

```
text-indent: -10px; padding-left: 10px;
```

but the size of the counter changes with font-size or increasing numbers.

http://codepen.io/ekadagami/pen/ezZEbo

Comment: Didn't quite understand the problem. The size of the counter would always change when font-size changes or there are bigger numbers right?

Comment: Position the psuedo-element? - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/oLxGeW

Comment: Or perhaps you meant ***negative*** `text-indent` - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/pbyWdM

Comment: @Paulie_D - of course. Type. Negative text-indent.

Comment: @Harry - The second line should always be vertically in-line exactly (!) with the first line after the numbering items. Not possible to demonstrate with proportional font.

Comment: So does Paulie_D's demo help you solve the problem?

Comment: @Paulie_D: The first codepen solved the problem by positioning the pseudo-element - thank you. The second solution is what I had in mind - not working.

Comment: So, is your problem solved or not? I am confused.

Comment: @Harry - Solved. Don't be confused. It's enough if one person is confused - and that's usually me.

Comment: This seems like a much better answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17515230/1561922

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Paulie_D got it right by positioning the pseudo-element:

```
ol > li {
  position: relative;
}

ol > li::before {
    counter-increment: paragraph;
    content: "§" counter(paragraph) " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: -1.5em;
}
```

http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/oLxGeW

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't my original code, but it's worth repeating for those who want an alternate solution for infinite depth.

I'm late to the party, but following solution works best for me:

```
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ol > li {
  display: table;
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}

ol > li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 0.6em;    
}

li ol > li {
  margin: 0;
}

li ol > li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
}
```

Links:

- [gist](https://gist.github.com/jirutka/32049196ab75547b7f47)
- [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a84enL8k/)