# <li>, bullet list not line up currently

Tags: html, css, less

On my website I have a bullet list with links.

The problem is when a link is a little long, it's split into two lines. It's fine!

However, when it divides in two lines, the second line is not located below the other.

How can I move the second line to the right so it fit with the other links?

```
<div class="test"> 
  <ul>
    <li><a href="menuItem.html">Yes</a></li>
    <li><a href="menuItem.html">Yes Yes Yes Yes</a></li>
    <li><a href="menuItem.html">Yes</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is an image of what I'm describing

[image: See Buletimage here]

Comment: can you share screen shot?

Comment: Show your CSS, as it's custom made bullt-point list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing your `list-style-position` is set to `inside`.

You should set it to `outside` (and play with the `margin-left` attribute if you want to keep the left offset).

[See jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/wcms91am/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the table layout:

```
ol {
    counter-reset: foo;
    display: table;
}

ol > li {
    counter-increment: foo;
    display: table-row;
}

ol > li::before {
    content: counter(foo) ".";
    display: table-cell; /* aha! */
    text-align: right;
}
```

source: [How to keep indent for second line in ordered lists via CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428720/how-to-keep-indent-for-second-line-in-ordered-lists-via-css)