# Align list item numbers with surrounding paragraphs

Tags: html, css

The list items may contain a couple of paragraphs, images, etc. They should all stay to the right of the item number.

```css
#page {
  width: 200px;
}

li {
  margin: 1em 0;
}
ol {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <p>Some text</p>
  <ol>
    <li>A list item</li>
    <li>A multiline list item another line</li>
    <li>
      <p>A list item containing blocks such as example images:</p>
      <div style="width:128px;height:48px;background:#CCC">Example<br/>Image</div>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <p>Some more text</p>
</div>
```

[image: Desired result]

Ideally I would prefer to keep the list tags rather than use a table or other set of positioned generic blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add some left padding to the `ol` element.

```css
#page {
  width: 200px;
}
ol {
  padding: 0 0 0 1em;
}
ol li {
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <p>Some text</p>
  <ol>
    <li>A list item</li>
    <li>A multiline list item another line</li>
  </ol>
  <p>Some more text</p>
</div>
```

You can also use CSS counter and add the list number via a pseudo element.

```css
#page {
  width: 200px;
}
ol {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
ol li {
  margin: 1em 0;
  counter-increment: number;
  display: flex;
}
ol li:before {
  content: counter(number)".";
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <p>Some text</p>
  <ol>
    <li>A list item</li>
    <li>A multiline list item another line</li>
  </ol>
  <p>Some more text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't think of `em` units on the horizontal and pixels required strange values. Is `1em` sure to be aligned for other fonts/sizes/etc. or this just luck?

Comment: @FireLancer It works fine, just be aware how you want it to look when the list number >= 10, I just added another approach using pseudo element, so you don't need to declare any width or padding.

Comment: Still not entirely sure why `1em` happens to be nearly right, but it does seem to be even with a font with different sized the numbers (`1` is perhaps a single pixel further right, but thats not noticeable). The pseudo element is definately an interesting approach, and if I use `width` instead of `margin-right`, works for different length points (e.g. `9` and `10`)

Answer (score 6):

check out `list-style-position` [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position)

```css
#page {
  width: 200px;
}
li {
  margin: 1em 0;
  /* this is what you want ↓ */
  list-style-position: inside;
}
ol {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <p>Some text</p>
  <ol>
    <li>A list item</li>
    <li>A multiline list item another line</li>
  </ol>
  <p>Some more text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I dint want to wrap the text under the number, also it broke when I put a block in it (didn't realize having a block in `li` was significant, will update)

Comment: have a look at this one too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428720/how-to-keep-indent-for-second-line-in-ordered-lists-via-css