# HTML: <li> elements rendering wrong in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, browser, html-lists

I am having a problem with **li** elements in Chrome. While in Firefox it shows like this:

[image: li elements in Firefox]

in Chrome, when the text is too long, the second line goes all the way to the beginning under the circle (li). Like this:

[image]

**How could I make that in Chrome (and all Browsers, the li elements behave correctly, like in Firefox?**

Comment: `ul * { padding:0; margin: 0; }`

Comment: this solution does not solve the problem

Comment: can you provide a link or something?

Comment: I am working local, sorry.

Comment: This might help --> http://stackoverflow.com/a/17514460/5561605

Comment: @RafaelMunoz you can always tunnel it online

Comment: My problem is that the li elements render OK in all Browsers, except for Chrome.