# Mapfish reports with textfields in markup html doesn't align text on bullets

Tags: html, report, markup, mapfish, bullet-span

I just want to **align the text on bullets in Mapfish or JasperReport**. The Mapfish html renderer is not exactly the same as in classic navigators.

**The HTML rendering in Mapfish or JasperReport is this one :** [**html rendering in Mapfish**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VISur.png)

**As you see, the second line is not aligned with bullet.**

My html content is :

```
<ul> 
  <li> 
    <font size='4'> 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ut... 
    </font> 
  </li> 
</ul>
```

The classic html renderer :

- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ut consequat elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis commodo quam a justo interdum, a facilisis diam finibus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos..

My textfield in .jrxml file has the markup as html

Thank you  !

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17515230/829301

Comment: Thank you for your help but that doesnt work :/

I tried with adding style="list-style-type: disc;list-style-position: inside;text-indent: -1em;padding-left: 1em;"> to li tags.