# How to stop :before element to push label text to the right

Tags: css

In my project we needed to style the checkbox element. I have seen that a common aproach is to style the `:before` element of the associated label instead.

So far I have managed to implement most of it, but I am having an issue with the `:before` element pushing the first line of the label text to the right.

I am trying to align all the text in the label to the right of the `:before` element, but so far the second line always starts at the same place than the `:before` element.

I am not a frontend dev, but I have tried changing padding, margin, left, position, etc. But I am at a loss.

This is how it looks:

[image]

**I want all the text of the label ot start at the red line.**

You can see what I have so far in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dzyann/er9m8yLw/).

```css
.container-box{
  display:block;
  max-width:200px;
}
.neat-checkbox {
  display: inline;
  width:40px;
}
.neat-checkbox input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 10px !important;
  display: none;
}
.neat-checkbox label {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  line-height: 17px !important;
}
.neat-checkbox label:before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f00c";
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  left: -5px;
  top: 0px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  line-height: 17px;
}
.neat-checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
  background-color: #2bb19e;
  border-color: #2bb19e;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f00c";
  font-size: 11px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  line-height: 17px;
}
.neat-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:focus + label::before {
  border-color: #66afe9;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class="container-box">
<div>
<label>Some other stuff</label>
</div>
<div class="neat-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-list" id="checkboxId_25600" name="name_25600" value="25600">
  <label for="checkboxId_25600">Label For Checkbox MOre more more</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428720/how-to-keep-indent-for-second-line-in-ordered-lists-via-css

Comment: Hi @Paulie_D, I put a working jsFidle, do you think I should copy the code here too?

Comment: @Paulie_D I tried the options on that link, and I can't get it to work, maybe because it is not a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the label some left padding and position the :before element absolutely within it. EG:

```css
.container-box {
  display: block;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.neat-checkbox {
  display: inline;
  width: 40px;
}

.neat-checkbox input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 10px !important;
  display: none;
}

.neat-checkbox label {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  line-height: 17px !important;
  display: inline-block; /* make it block-level */
  position: relative; /* so that child elements can be positioned relative to it */
  padding-left: 25px; /* allow some space for the pseudo checkbox */
}

.neat-checkbox label:before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f00c";
  color: white;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block; /* make it block-level */
  position: absolute; /* give an absolute position (defaults to 0,0) */
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  line-height: 17px;
}

.neat-checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked+label:before {
  background-color: #2bb19e;
  border-color: #2bb19e;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f00c";
  font-size: 11px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  line-height: 17px;
}

.neat-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:focus+label::before {
  border-color: #66afe9;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class="container-box">
  <div>
    <label>Some other stuff</label>
  </div>
  <div class="neat-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-list" id="checkboxId_25600" name="name_25600" value="25600">
    <label for="checkboxId_25600">Label For Checkbox MOre more more</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had tried doing what you suggested but I didnt set correctly, as you did, the display for the label and its :before. It is hard to understand sometimes the combination of the different display values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are moving the checkbox using position relative, so the original space is preserved but you just move the visual 5px to the left.

You can add a `margin-right: -5px` if you use `left: -5px` or remove the `left` property and just use `margin-left: -5px` instead.