# How to keep indent for second line in nested unordered list using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428720/how-to-keep-indent-for-second-line-in-ordered-lists-via-css) and it helped me. But now I need to keep the second line text to be indented for nested ul li. How to achieve this?

Example is below.

```
-List item
-List item
  - It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable 
 content of a page when looking at its layout. 
-List item
```

My current CSS is

```
ul li {
    list-style-type: disc;
    line-height: 1.6;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Montserrat-Light";
  list-style-position: outside;
}

ul li li {
    list-style-type: circle;
    line-height: 1.6;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Montserrat-Light";
  list-style-position: inside;
    text-indent: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the updated solution from the answer:

```
ul {
   list-style-position: outside;
}
```

Here is an example:

```css
p {
    margin: 7px 0;
}
li {
    list-style-type: disc;
    padding-left: 1em;
}
ol {
  list-style-position: outside;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>
<ol>
   <li>Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio nisi, euismod in, pharetra a, ultricies in, diam. Sed arcu. Cras consequat.</li>
   <li>Sed adipiscing ornare risus. Morbi est est, blandit sit amet, sagittis vel, euismod vel, velit. Pellentesque egestas sem. Suspendisse commodo ullamcorper magna.</li>
   <li>Nulla sed leo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</li>
   <li>
      Fusce lacinia arcu et nulla. Nulla vitae mauris non felis mollis faucibus.
      <ol>
         <li>Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio nisi, euismod in, pharetra a, ultricies in, diam. Sed arcu. Cras consequat.</li>
         <li>Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus.</li>
         <li>Phasellus ultrices nulla quis nibh. Quisque a lectus. Donec consectetuer ligula vulputate sem tristique cursus. Nam nulla quam, gravida non, commodo a, sodales sit amet, nisi.</li>
         <li>Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</li>
      </ol>
   </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Element ol not allowed as child of element ol

Answer (score -1):

You have to be careful nesting `ul` and `ol`. They can be nested inside of a `li`, however.

Try this

```css
.none{
  list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li class="none">
    <ul>
      <li>Child item 1</li>
      <li>Child item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```