# TiddlyWiki. How to change list style and align?

Tags: tiddlywiki

Could you please clarify how I can change list style and align in TiddlyWiki WikiText?

Now in my file (list style without indents and justified):
[image]

I would like to get (list style with indents and align left):

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I just downloaded the Getting Started from https://tiddlywiki.com/ and when I make a list it is indented the way you expect.

Comment: @Jerry Jeremiah Hi Jerry, thank you. Yes, blank file works fine. However when I upgraded my old file to last version I got wrong format... It must be my customization but I have no idea what should be fixed.

Comment: This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428720/how-to-keep-indent-for-second-line-in-ordered-lists-via-css might be the same as yours.  If that would potentially help, I have no ide where to put it in your file.

Comment: @Jerry Jeremiah It was two options from Drift Tweaks plugin: Show Bullets & Numbers and Check this box if you use long bullet or numbered lists. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by unchecking two options from Drift Tweaks plugin:

```
Show Bullets & Numbers
Check this box if you use long bullet or numbered lists
```

[image]