# Increase Space Between Ordered List Numbers and List Item Text

Tags: css, html-lists, listitem

I have an example codepen (https://codepen.io/jon424/pen/YzeBdGK?editors=1100) where I am trying to use custom numbering for ordered lists. The issue occurs when the text for the `li` wraps to the next line. When this happens (see my list item number 3 in the example), the text is vertically aligned with the ordered list number. I would like to have a margin between the number and the entire content for the wrapping `li` text so that the ordered list number is not in the same vertical alignment as the `li` content when it wraps. I would like to try to keep this with only `ol` and `li` tags, avoiding a `span`, and am looking for suggestions.

*There is a similar question on SO regarding [keeping the indent for the second line of an ordered list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428720/how-to-keep-indent-for-second-line-in-ordered-lists-via-css) , but after researching this approach I am still puzzled with how to keep my list number styles consistent while allowing for the spacing between the numbers and the text. Currently, while trying the* `table-layout`  *approach, the border radius around the list item is also effected by the display, causing the circles around the numbers to be different sizes depending on the content of the list item*.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

HTML

```html
<ol>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>Longer List item Longer List item Longer List item Longer List item Longer List item Longer List item Longer List item Longer List item Longer List item Longer List item Longer List item Longer List item</li>
   <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
</ol>
```

CSS

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: counter-function;
}
li {
  counter-increment: counter-function;
  margin: 0.25rem;
}
li::before {
  content: counter(counter-function);
  background: red;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 2rem;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"not in the same vertical alignment"*? How is this **supposed** to look?

Comment: Do you mean you want the number vertically **centered** with the text?

Comment: I mean that - when the text is long enough to wrap to a second line (see the long <li> example in my codepen), the text on the second line appears directly beneath the list number. I would like the list number to be separated from the content with a `margin-right` or something to keep the numbers and the list content

Comment: That's what the linked duplicate does but OK

Comment: right, and I was having trouble keeping the style of the list numbers consistent (the circle border around the number) with that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flexbox on the `li`

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: counter-function;
}

li {
  counter-increment: counter-function;
  margin: 0.25rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* adjust as needed */
}

li::before {
  content: counter(counter-function);
  background: red;
  flex: 0 0 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 2rem;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 1rem; /* adjust as needed */
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li><span>Longer List item Longer List item Longer List item Longer List item Longer List item Longer List item Longer List item Longer List item Longer List item Longer List item Longer List item Longer List item</span></li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
</ol>
```