# Is there a way to make numbers in an ordered list bold?

Tags: css, html-lists

Is there any CSS selector to attach some style to the numerical part of an ordered list only?

I have HTML like:

```
<ol>
   <li>a</li>
   <li>b</li>
   <li>c</li>
</ol>
```

Which should output:

```
1.a
2.b
3.c
```

I need to make 1., 2. and 3. **bold**, while leaving a, b, and c regular.

I am aware of the `<span>` workaround...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make ABC Ordered List Items Have Bold Style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862878/make-abc-ordered-list-items-have-bold-style)

Comment: just use a counter-reset and list-style-type: none  http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/fdbEm

Comment: ol > li::marker {
  font-weight: bold;
}

solution provided below is the best answer for this question please upvote

Answer (score 110, accepted):

A new [`::marker` pseudo-element selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker) has been added to [CSS Pseudo-Elements Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4/#marker-pseudo), which makes styling list item numbers in bold as simple as

```css
ol > li::marker {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

It is currently [supported by Firefox 68+, Chrome/Edge 86+, and Safari 11.1+](https://caniuse.com/css-marker-pseudo).

Comment: Best solution in 2021. This answer is be far more preferable than the others above

Comment: best solution for this question but not rated above please vote and support

Comment: This should now be the accepted answer. Earlier answers are just clever hacks.

Comment: Accepted as the answer for 2022. Thanks.

Comment: Superb. Progressive enhancement all the way. Had previously put in the earlier hacks, but then needed to account for the indenting as well - this way just allows the li to flow as it would naturally.

Answer (score 115):

using The **[Counter-increment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-increment)** CSS property

```css
ol {
  margin:0 0 1.5em;
  padding:0;
  counter-reset:item;
}
 
ol>li {
  margin:0;
  padding:0 0 0 2em;
  text-indent:-2em;
  list-style-type:none;
  counter-increment:item;
}
 
ol>li:before {
  display:inline-block;
  width:1.5em;
  padding-right:0.5em;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:right;
  content:counter(item) ".";
}
```

```html
<ol>
   <li>a</li>
   <li>b</li>
   <li>c</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: If your LIs contain Ps or other block level elements, you need to also undo the text-indent, like so...
`
ol > li * {
  text-indent: 0;
}
`
edit: sorry it looks like code formatting is broken in comments.

Comment: Thanks for adding the text-indent too! This solution was perfect!

Comment: When adding this custom css here: https://www.hlbenefits.com/best-vegan-vegetarian-protein-sources-2016/ I get a strange result when numbering becomes 1.1. | 2.1. | 3.1. | and so on. The second (1) gets bold. So basically it adds another numbering without counting. Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

Comment: @faceoff Set `list-style-type` to `none` to get rid of the first (native) number. Also, the approach suggested in this answer is clever, but makes it difficult to left-align the text properly if the `li` line-breaks.

Comment: This doesn't respect lists with a specified li type="a", type="i", etc. If you have a list with alpha order and one item has a nested list with roman order, all of them become decimal numbers.

Comment: @stefan-gentz's answer was easier for me to implement with deep lists and different list types throughout (A,1,a)

Answer (score 35):

Another easy possibility would be to wrap the list item content into a `<p>`, style the `<li>` as bold and the `<p>` as regular. This would be also preferable from an IA point of view, especially when `<li>`s can contain sub-lists (to avoid mixing text nodes with block level elements).

Full example for your convenience:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ordered list items with bold numbers</title>
        <style>
            ol li {
                font-weight:bold;
            }
            li > p {
                font-weight:normal;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ol>
            <li>
                <p>List Item 1</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Liste Item 2</p>
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <p>Sub List Item 1</p>
                     </li>
                    <li>
                        <p>Sub List Item 2</p>
                     </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>List Item 3.</p>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you prefer a more generic approach (that would also cover other scenarios like `<li>`s with descendants other than `<p>`, you might want to use `li > *` instead of `li > p`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ordered list items with bold numbers</title>
        <style>
            ol li {
                font-weight:bold;
            }
            li > * {
                font-weight:normal;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ol>
            <li>
                <p>List Item 1</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Liste Item 2</p>
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <p>Sub List Item 1</p>
                     </li>
                    <li>
                        <p>Sub List Item 2</p>
                     </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>List Item 3.</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <code>List Item 4.</code>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

(Check the list item 4 here which is ol/li/code and not ol/li/p/code here.)

Just make sure to use the selector `li > *` and not `li *`, if you only want to style block level descendants as regular, but not also inlines like "foo `<strong>`bold word`</strong>` foo."

Comment: This is a lighter and better approach than the two approaches listed above. If you want this in a master CSS file but you do not want this to be app-wide, use classes instead (i.e., ol -> class-name-1, li -> class-name-2).

Comment: Brilliant! This should even be the accepted answer. And with the following additional code you can normalize the nested lists without the need for `<p>`s in them: `.listClassName li {font-weight: bold;} .listClassName li > *, .listClassName li > * > *  {font-weight: normal;}`

Comment: While less generally flexible, this is a much more direct answer to the originally proposed question.

Comment: What is *"IA"*?

Comment: @peter-mortensen: IA = Information Architecture

Comment: A much better answer in my opinion than the accepted answer - simple to implement, thanks!

Answer (score 21):

[JSFiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/B3A7y/)

```
ol {
    counter-reset: item;
}
ol li { display: block }

ol li:before {
    content: counter(item) ". ";
    counter-increment: item;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar issue while writing a newsletter. So I had to inline the style this way:

```
<ol>
    <li style="font-weight:bold"><span style="font-weight:normal">something</span></li>
    <li style="font-weight:bold"><span style="font-weight:normal">something</span></li>
    <li style="font-weight:bold"><span style="font-weight:normal">something</span></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: The only solution that also works in emails (in all email templates, as we cannot provide css there)

Comment: Works for email. Genius. It's one of those "omg it's so simple that I'm stupid for not thinking of that" solutions. Great job dude.

Answer (score 5):

Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21369918/2526049 from dcodesmith has a side effect that turns all types of lists numeric.
`<ol type="a">` will show 1. 2. 3. 4. rather than a. b. c. d.

```
ol {
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: item;
}

ol > li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 2em;
  text-indent: -2em;
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-increment: item;
}

ol > li:before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
  content: counter(item) ".";
}

/* Add support for non-numeric lists */

ol[type="a"] > li:before {
  content: counter(item, lower-alpha) ".";
}
ol[type="i"] > li:before {
  content: counter(item, lower-roman) ".";
}
```

The above code adds support for lowercase letters, lowercase roman numerals. At the time of writing browsers do not differentiate between upper and lower case selectors for type so you can only pick uppercase or lowercase for your alternate ol types I guess.

Comment: There is more than one previous answer. Do you mean all of them or one in particular? Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51314068/edit) (but ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar).

Answer (score 4):

If you are using [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) 4:

```
<ol class="font-weight-bold">
    <li><span class="font-weight-light">Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit.</span></li>
    <li><span class="font-weight-light">Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit.</span></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: It sounds very simple. I will try install Bootstrap 4 to try it.

Answer (score 3):

This is an update for dcodesmith's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21369918/1668200

The proposed solution also works when the text is longer (i.e. the lines need to wrap): **[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DruxN/438/)**

When you're using a grid system, you might need to do one of the following (at least this is true for Foundation 6 - couldn't reproduce it in the Fiddle):

- Add `box-sizing:content-box;` to the list or its container
- OR change `text-indent:-2em;` to `-1.5em`

P.S.: I wanted to add this as an edit to the original answer, but it was rejected.

Answer (score 0):

You also could put <span style="font-weight:normal"> around a,b,c and then bold the ul in the CSS.

#### Example

```
ul {
    font-weight: bold;
}

<ul><li><span style="font-weight:normal">a</span></li></ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Pretty late answer, but hopefully someone will find this useful**

I had a situation like this:

1. **List item**

   a. List item

Where the first item was `<strong>`, the sub-element was normal weight and the '1.' just **wouldn't** bold.

My solution was via jQuery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('ol').has('li').has('strong')) {
            $('ol ').css('font-weight', 'bold');
            $('ol > li > ol').css('font-weight', 'normal');
        }
     });
</script>
```

Hopefully this helps someone!