# Custom counter for ol

Tags: css

Changing the counter in ol/li is known CSS trick with many references like [this one](https://css-tricks.com/custom-list-number-styling/).

I use this trick to have multiple `<ol>` elements with the same counter. I also want to have the correct margins for multiline text. For this, it is suggested to use `::marker` like the example below (Using `::before` makes the numbers part of the paragraph as opposed to being in the margins). This works well in Firefox, but only Firefox. Not on my iPhone and not in Chrome (as explained [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/m/marker/)).

Is there a better solution that works on all browsers?

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>

    div.one-counter {
        counter-reset: bibitem;
    }

    div.one-counter ol{
        max-width: 200px;
    }

    div.one-counter ol li {
        counter-increment: bibitem;
        padding: 0 0 0 .3em;   
    }

    div.one-counter ol li::marker {
        content: counter(bibitem) ".";
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="one-counter">
    <h3>First</h3>
    <ol>
      <li>  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse nec augue
        vitae tortor dignissim aliquam.</li>
      <li>Nulla facilisi. Duis venenatis ipsum at mauris elementum, ac commodo quam tempus. </li>
    </ol>
    <h3>Second</h3>
    <ol>
      <li>  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse nec augue
        vitae tortor dignissim aliquam.</li>
      <li>Nulla facilisi. Duis venenatis ipsum at mauris elementum, ac commodo quam tempus.</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ::marker pseudo element is not supported in all browsers as referenced [on MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker). It is currently only a working draft. I suggest using the ::before element and adjusting the margin or padding to achieve the desired positioning.

Comment: Is there a way to have the correct positioning that would always work for all list and font sizes? The margins don’t have a fixed width so I am unsure how to do this correctly.

Comment: If you use em spacing it should be relative to the font size. margin-left: -0.5em; play around with that. 

Comment: Thanks! I found this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369843/is-there-any-way-to-make-numbers-in-ordered-list-bold) which contains reasonable spacing that worked for my case.

Answer (score 1):

## Use One List

1. Wrap each `<h3>` in an `<li>` and place them where you want them within `<ol>`.
2. Remove all the CSS that relates to `<ol>` and `<li>`
3. Add this ruleset: `.hdr { list-style: none; margin-left: -40px; }`
4. Assign `.hdr` to each `<h3>`: `<h3 class='hdr'>...`
5. Assign the rest of the `<li>` a `[value=N]` `N` being the number position:

   ```
    <li value='1'>First Item</li>
   ```

The [`[value]` `<li>` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Styling_lists#value) is used very little because in situations where there's a large amount of `<li>` and/or `<li>` are dynamically generated, it would be problematic. See ***Example 2*** of the demo to address that problem.

The following demo has two examples:

1. ***Example 1*** is manual assignment of `[value]`
2. ***Example 2*** is programmatic assignment of `[value]` (two lines of JavaScript)

---

### Demo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <style>
    .hdr {
      list-style: none;
      margin-left: -40px;
    }
    
    /* For demo purposes */ 
    code {
      font-family: Consolas;
      color: green;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1><code>[value]</code> Attribute</h1>
  <h2>Example 1</h2>
  <p>List A -- <code>ol#A</code> -- <code>[value]</code> assigned manually</p>
  <ol id='A'>
    <li class='hdr'>
      <h3>First</h3>
    </li>
    <li value='1'> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse nec augue vitae tortor dignissim aliquam.</li>
    <li value='2'>Nulla facilisi. Duis venenatis ipsum at mauris elementum, ac commodo quam tempus. </li>
    <li class='hdr'>
      <h3>Second</h3>
    </li>
    <li value='3'> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse nec augue vitae tortor dignissim aliquam.</li>
    <li value='4'>Nulla facilisi. Duis venenatis ipsum at mauris elementum, ac commodo quam tempus.</li>
  </ol>


  <h2>Example 2</h2>
  <p>List B -- <code>ol#B</code> -- <code>[value]</code> assigned programmatically. See <code>&lt;script&gt;</code> block at end of source.</p>
  <ol id='B'>
    <li class='hdr'>
      <h3>First</h3>
    </li>
    <li> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse nec augue vitae tortor dignissim aliquam.</li>
    <li>Nulla facilisi. Duis venenatis ipsum at mauris elementum, ac commodo quam tempus. </li>
    <li class='hdr'>
      <h3>Second</h3>
    </li>
    <li> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse nec augue vitae tortor dignissim aliquam.</li>
    <li>Nulla facilisi. Duis venenatis ipsum at mauris elementum, ac commodo quam tempus.</li>
  </ol>

  <script>
    /*
    - Collect all <li> in <ol id='B'> that is 
      NOT <li class='hdr'> into a NodeList
    - Your selector can be more generic if using only
      one list: li:not(.hdr)
    */
    const items = document.querySelectorAll('#B li:not(.hdr)');

    /*
    - Iterate through NodeList and assign [value=index+1]
      to each <li>
    */
    items.forEach((li, idx) => li.setAttribute('value', idx + 1));
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. The example I have is simplified. I cannot use one list in my situation and have to use two.

Comment: A javascript solution like your second example (or based on `ol.start` instead of `li.value`) seems to be the best way to do this. I was just wondering if CSS can handle this.